# Code Igniter Count Function

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I want to do is I want to count the total records from the table called "songs_tbl" from my database. So I wrote this function in controller.

```
private function getHeaderInfo()
{
         $total_songs = $songs->count('distinct songs_tbl.song_id');
         $this->mysmarty->assign('total_songs',$total_songs);
}
```

I got this error

> **Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in**

Any suggestion ? Thank you.

With Regards,

Comment: is it because of $songs ? Yea i forgot to delcare $songs, what should i declare ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
$this->db->count_all('songs_tbl');
```

or if you want the distinct in there you will need to do something like this:

```
$this->db->select('song_id');
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->from('songs_tbl');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->num_rows();
```

As there is/was? an issue with using `count_all_results()` function and DISTINCT

***EDIT***

I have never used smarty but based on the code in the question I imagine something like this might work, please correct me if I am wrong:

```
private function getHeaderInfo()
{
    $total_songs = get_all_songs();// This function should be called through a model
    $this->mysmarty->assign('total_songs',$total_songs);
}

function get_all_songs(){ //THIS SHOULD BE IN A MODEL
    $this->db->select('song_id');
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->from('songs_tbl');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

***Edit 2***

My suggested layout would be something along these lines (UNTESTED) using CodeIgniter WITHOUT smarty:

**Model Song.php**

```
class Song extends CI_Model {
    //Constructor and other functions

    function count_all_songs(){
        $this->db->select('song_id');
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->from('songs_tbl');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
}
```

**Controller Songs.php**

```
class Song extends CI_Controller {
    //Constructor and other functions

    function index(){ //This could be any page
        $this->load->model('Song'); //Could be in constructor
        $total_songs = $this->Song->count_all_songs();
        $this->load->view('songs_index.html', array('total_songs' => $total_songs));
    }
}
```

**View songs_index.html**

```
<html><head></head><body>
    Total Songs: <?php echo $total_songs ?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: thanks. But I am using with smarty, how can i execute that function in template side ?

Comment: $total_songs = get_all_songs();// This function should be called through a model
$this->mysmarty->assign('total_songs',$total_songs);

Both lines should be in the same model file with function get_all_songs ? If i put in same model file, i got the blank page when i executed.

Comment: anything should i put in controller ? I put the above code at my model file and execute the function like this on template side <{$total_songs}>, nothing happens. I didn't see any count nor errors as well.

Comment: thanks it's works. I just change the this line to this   $total_songs = $this->smarty->assign("total_songs", number_format($this->Song->count_all_songs("")));

Answer (score 1):

You could query the table and request a count from the table itself, like this:

```
$result = mysql_query(SELECT count(*) FROM songs_tbl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo $this->db->count_all('songs_tbl');
```

It permits you to determine the number of rows in a particular table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$query = $this->db->get('distinct');
        if($query->num_rows())
        {
            return $query->num_rows();
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
```